# Select from database where ID = $id_variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have in my database a table called `posts` which has a column `poster_id` linked to `id` in `users` table through a foreign key.

Now, I wanna select some data from `users` table where the id is equal to `poster_id`. I am using PDO, and I read many articles about it but I cannot still fix the bug I have.

My code that selects the posts from `posts` is:

```
$post_records = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY RAND()');
$post_records->execute();
$post_results = $post_records->fetchall();

$post_data = NULL;
$posts_count = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) FROM posts")->fetchColumn();

foreach ($post_results as $post_data) {

}
```

The code that selects the user username from `users` where `id` is equal to the poster_id:

```
$poster_id = $post_data['id'];

// Collect poster data from database
$poster_records = $conn->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = {$poster_id}');
$poster_records->execute();
$poster_results = $post_records->fetchall();

$poster_data = NULL;
foreach ($poster_results as $poster_data) {

}
```

`posts` table structure: http://prntscr.com/kh8gqz

`users` table structure: https://prnt.sc/kh8h0f

Foreign key is linking between `poster_id` in `posts` table and `id` in `users` table.

Extra: This code gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''users' WHERE 'id' = '1'' at line 1 in F:\xampp\htdocs\home.php:57 Stack trace: #0 F:\xampp\htdocs\home.php(57): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in F:\xampp\htdocs\home.php on line 57
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the table structure too?

Comment: @JohnT Edited the post and added a screenshot from the table structure as I don't know how to write it in that | -- name -- | way

Comment: Check Josés answer. Replacing ' with " probably solves it.

Comment: It didn't work sadly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In here:

```
$poster_records = $conn->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = {$poster_id}');
```

you're using single quotes for the SQL statement, so the string will be taken literally, meaning the variable `$poster_id` won't expand to its value. Replace the statement with double quotes and try again:

```
$poster_records = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = {$poster_id}");
```

EDIT: Okay, if that didn't work, try a prepared statement with binding parameters, like this:

```
$poster_records = $conn->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ?');
$poster_records->bind_param('i', $poster_id);
$poster_records->execute();
```

EDIT 2: using PDO:

```
$poster_records = $conn->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = :id');
$poster_records->execute([':id' => $poster_id]);
```

Comment: It didn't change anything sadly.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try it and check if it works now.

Comment: Still didn't work
it says `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param()`

Comment: Ohhh, you're using PDO, not mysqli like I assumed. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Do I have to use `fetchall`?

Comment: Not necessarily, you could use `fetch` as well, but that only returns one row.